# How to share a variable across multiple source files in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, singleton

## Summary of my goal

I want to make a **global instance** of a declared class shared between multiple `.cpp` files in **C++**.

## Explanations

*If you want to go fast, you can jump just after **Expectations**.*

I know that **many** people said that I *shouldn't use global variables for too much reasons*... Read my explanations to understand why I do want them.

**Step 1:**
I was doing a **C++** program with a class defined in a header file.
*(The class's functions were declared in a cpp file.)*

To explain it, **I'll use a over-simplified hypothetical** code. *(Not the actual one.)*

Simplified hypothetical `Class.h`'s code:

```cpp
class Class {
    public:
        Class(intx,int y); //Does a lot of things

        int OP1(int x); //Dummy operation
        int OP2(int x); //Dummy operation
    private:
        type ManyVars;
}
```

Simplified hypothetical `main.cpp`'s code

```cpp
#include "Class.h"

Class Member(140,360);  //Declares it with parameters

bool Func1(int x) { //Dummy function
    int y = Member.OP2(x);
    return x > Member.OP1(y);
}

bool Func2(int x) { //Dummy function
    int y = Member.OP2(x) * x;
    return x > Member.OP1(y) +1;
}


int main() {
    int x;

    std::cin >> x;

    y = Func2(x);
    z = Func1(y * x / 5);

    return Func2(z) + x / y;
}
```

As far I was, everything was working fine, but **the code was monstrously big** in `main.cpp` because I had over 16 functions including 2 big ones!
*(I show only two functions in my example to be simple.)*

**Step 2:**
**To make the code easier** to read, I've moved the small functions in two others files `Funcs.cpp` and `Funcs.h`, *like a library*.
Then I moved the big functions into a new `.cpp` file for each one to after being included in another header file.
*(Hidden in example because it's like `Funcs.cpp`.)*

So, now the hypothetical `main.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
#include "Class.h"
#include "Funcs.h"

Class Member(140,360);

int main() {
    int x;

    std::cin >> x;

    int y = Func2(x);
    int z = Func1(y * x / 5);

    return Func2(z) + x / y;
}
```

And the hypothetical `Funcs.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
#include "Class.h"
#include "Funcs.h"

bool Func1(int x) {
    int y = Member.OP2(x);
    return x > Member.OP1(y);
}

bool Func2(int x) {
    int y = Member.OP2(x) * x;
    return x > Member.OP1(y) +1;
}
```

Now comes an issue: `Member` is only **defined in** `main.cpp` **but I need it also in** `Funcs.cpp` *(and the others function files too)*.

**Step 3:**
I tried to add another input value of type `Class` for each function and put `Member` in it when used. It **worked but the functions look awful**! *I don't want an extra parameter for each function!* So I reverted the code to Step 1 for the moment.

## Expectations

What I want is any way to **share the same instance between them**. *It's basically a global variable.*
I want to keep same functions. `int y = Member.OP2(x)` **mustn't change** *whereas the beginning  of each file could be changed*.
I would like to be able to declare multiple such `Member`s (I won't, but it must be possible to do it).

**Does anyone know a way to share instances that way?**

*Please tell me if something is unclear.*

Comment: But `Member` is not a member, it's a global variable. You share it between different source files using the same method you use for any global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Member` is a global variable. Share it using the usual technique that you would use for any global variable, declare it in a header file and define it (once) in a source file.

In a header file (say Class.h)

```
extern Class Member;
```

In main.cpp

```
Class Member(140,360);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to using globals is to exploit the *Singleton Pattern* by storing unique instance of the Class in static storage (*Construct On First Use Idiom*).

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247912/extern-vs-singleton-class) that explains the difference between this and john's answer (c.f. the C++ FAQ that addresses what is [*initialisation order fiasco*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) and [how does this approach avoid it](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use)).

```
template<int x, int y>
class Class
{
public:
    static Class & get_instance()
    {
        static Class instance; // <- called only once!
        return instance;
    }

    Class(const Class &) = delete;

    Class & operator=(const Class &) = delete;

    bool OP1(int a)
    {
        return a > x;
    }

    bool OP2(int b)
    {
        return b > y;
    }

private:
    Class() = default;

    ~Class() = default;
};
```

Then, you can get reference to the instance by the `get_instance()` method as

```
auto& Member = Class<140,360>::get_instance();
```